# A question on permutation groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ be three involutions of a finite set such that $a_1 a_2 a_3$ is a cyclic permutation. Is the group generated by $a_1, a_2, a_3$ the symmetric group?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "a cyclic permutation of $S$?

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It's been deleted, but the old question was at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454759/whether-the-group-generated-by-involutions-is-the-symmetric-group

Comment: For what it's worth, one of the comments provided what seems to be as strong an answer to the question as possible: consider $a_1 = (12)(34), a_2 = (23)(45), a_3 = (34)(15)$; then $a_1 a_2 a_3 = (13524)$ is cyclic, but every element is in $A_5$.

Comment: For the revised question, a random search in $S_6$ quickly found: $a,b,c=(1, 2)(3, 4)(5, 6),(1, 6)(2, 5)(3, 4),(1, 6)(2, 4)(3, 5)$, $abc=(1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3)$, $\langle a,b,c \rangle=12$.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but if $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$ all leave some element $s \in S$ fixed, then so does every element of the group they generate. E.g. if we interpret the example in the comment above as acting on $S = \{1, \ldots, 7\}$ instead of $\{1, \ldots, 6\}$ then it is clear that they do not generate the whole symmetry group since they won't generate any element that sends 7 to 1 (or any other element)

Comment: Still I think the more general question of what sets of involutions generate the symmetry group is very interesting, I'd like to learn more about that and hope some answer to this question can shed some light on that

Comment: @Vincent But $a_1a_2a_3$ is supposed to be a cycle of length $|S|$ on $S$. So there can be no counterexample with $|S|$ odd, because such a cycle would be an even permutation, but I am guessing that for all even $|S|$ there is a counterexample in which the $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ is dihedral of order $2|S|$. This is hardly research level mathmatics.

Comment: @Derek Ah a cycle of length $|S|$. I just thought they meant any cycle! That makes the question a lot more understandable. The idea about dihedral groups sounds promising, can you elaborate this, maybe as an answer?

Answer (score 9):

For $n \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, let $m = n/2$ and define the following permutations in $S_n$:

$$c := (1,2,3,\ldots,n-1,n),$$
$$a_1:=(1,n)(2,n-1) \cdots (m,m+1),$$
$$a_2 := c^m = (1,m+1)(2,m+2) \cdots (m,n),$$
$$ a_3 := a_2 a_1 c.$$

Then $a_1a_2a_3 = c$, with $\langle a_1,a_2,a_3 \rangle = \langle a_1,c \rangle$ the dihedral group of order $2n$.

Since $a_1$ and $a_2$ are products of $m$ transpositions, they are odd permutations, and $a_3= a_1c^{m+1}$ with $m+1$ even is conjugate to $a_1$ in the dihedral group, so that is too.

Comment: Beautiful solution! And also a very nice presentation (pun intended)